# How to fetch record from table based on post ip address in laravel using eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am want to fetch record based on user post ip address. I am using eloquent ORM. 
in such case which format ip address should be stored in database.

```
$ip = '192.255.365.25';
$employee = Employee::find($ip);
```

not able to fetch full record for respective rows

Comment: `find()` used to find a row using primary key of the table

Comment: so how to get data any idea ?

Comment: you can find it by using `first()` method, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()`used to retrieve a model by its primary key, you can use `first()` as below

```
$ip = '192.255.365.25';
$employee = Employee::where('ip', $ip)->first();
```

for more see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)